# elasticsearch connect to my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, backend

I want to use elasticsearch database in my laravel project but when I want to migrate my model I encourage to some errors.

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_19' (tried: ext\oci8_19 (The specified module could not be found), ext\php_oci8_19.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_firebird' (tried: ext\pdo_firebird (The specified module could not be found), ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: ext\pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found), ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = api_proj and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\*\*\*\*\api-proj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")

PDO::__construct()
```

Comment: Possibly using different Port for MySQL than using in your Code

Comment: This is not elasticsearch error. As i can understand few warning is about to load library. Which you need to install and the exception is related to table.